# SeleniumLibrary Dialogs User Dialog Box Will Not Go Away

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, dialog, selenium-rc, browser-automation

In this script I ask the user for the username, password & router serial for Robot Framework to navigate the website & enter the info to login & search for that router serial.  The script works to ask for all three credentials but never goes away when you click the OK button after entering the serial.
The rest of the script will work & fill in the information but that dialog box will not go away.  Any help is greatly appreciated for this Python novice.

=======================================================================

```py
*** Settings ***

Documentation    A script that enables SSH on a router in software specified by serial number from the user.

Suite Setup  Setup chromedriver

Library  SeleniumLibrary

Library  OperatingSystem

Library  Dialogs




*** Keywords ***

Setup chromedriver
  Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ${EXECDIR}/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/Automation/chromedriver




*** Variables ***

${url}  https://eco.company.com/manage

#${serial}  MQ25761000110

${deviceusernum}  Device.Users.User.7.X_OUI_RemoteAccess.1.X_OUI_LANRestriction

${key1}  ACCESS_ENABLE

${deviceuserpass}  Device.Users.User.7.Password

${key2}  P@ssword1

${deviceport}  Device.Users.User.7.X_OUI_RemoteAccess.1.Port

${key3}  22



*** Test Cases ***

Get Credentials

    ${ECO_username}=   Get Value From User   Enter ECO user name  admin
    Log To Console  \n${ECO_username}
    ${ECO_password}=   Get Value From User   Enter ECO password  hidden=yes
    Log To Console  \n${ECO_password}
    ${ECO_serial}=   Get Value From User   Enter router serial  serial
    Log To Console  \n${ECO_serial}


    [Tags]             smoke test

    Open Browser  ${url}  chrome
```

[Stuck Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRcRV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue myself by not using the RPA.Dialogs library (which is depreciated).  I used the RPA.Assistant library instead with this code:

*** Settings ***
Documentation       A robot that enables SSH on a router in a GUI specified by serial number from the user.

Library             RPA.Browser.Selenium
Library             RPA.Assistant
Library             OperatingSystem
Library             RPA.RobotLogListener

Suite Setup         Setup chromedriver

*** Variables ***

${url}                  https://gui.com/manage

${deviceusernum}        Device.Users.User.7.X_OUI_RemoteAccess.1.X_OUI_LANRestriction

${key1}                 ACCESS_ENABLE_ALL

${deviceuserpass}       Device.Users.User.7.Password

${key2}                 P@ssw0rd1

${deviceport}           Device.Users.User.7.X_OUI_RemoteAccess.1.Port

${key3}                 22

*** Test Cases ***
Enable SSH
[Tags]    smoke test

```
${username}=    Collect username
${password}=    Collect password
${serial}=    Collect serial

Open Browser    ${url}    chrome

Maximize Browser Window
```

*** Keywords ***
Setup chromedriver
Set Environment Variable    webdriver.chrome.driver    ${EXECDIR}/Users/me/Documents/Python/chromedriver

Collect username
Add heading    GUI User Name
Add text input    username    label=Username
Add submit buttons    buttons=OK,Cancel    default=OK
${result}=    Run dialog    height=250    location=Center
RETURN    ${result.username}

Collect password
Add heading    GUI Password
Add password input    password    label=Password
Add submit buttons    buttons=OK,Cancel    default=OK
${result}=    Run dialog    height=250    location=Center
RETURN    ${result.password}

Collect serial
Add heading    Router Serial
Add text input    serial    label=Router Serial #
Add submit buttons    buttons=OK,Cancel    default=OK
${result}=    Run dialog    height=250    location=Center
RETURN    ${result.serial}